# Dynamic pages with PHP and AMP

Tags: php, dynamic, static, amp-html, webshop

I've recently been looking into AMP for my webshop but in every post, thread, etc. I've read that AMP is purely static.

So my question is if it's possible or even worth it to make dynamic pages with AMP without creating a static page for each product page.

The reason I don't want static pages is because the prices get updated almost every week.

Comment: @JustBaron Is there any documentation/framework for this? I think I would be fine on my own yet I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: Apologies, I mis-read your question.

Comment: @SaltyPotato! AMP is for static pages but you can use it with dynamic content. By reading amp documentation and example you can filter your php dynamic content according to its tags, please refer : https://ampbyexample.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's a free and easy to use library that could generate a static or dynamic amp site because it's generated by procedures (code).

https://github.com/EFTEC/AMPGeneratorOne

It's a demo page: (the footer and navigation was cut)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create google amp dynamic pages with PHP, node js or codeignitor or so..

you can check this out!

[Step-by-step | Convert Dynamic Amp Page in PHP](https://doodleish.com/Web-Knowledges/81/convert-to-dynamic-amp-pages.html)